# Proposing a numerically sound algorithm for a function as it approaches 0

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Suppose I have the function

$f(x) = 1 + x - \sin(x)/(x*e^{x})$

I am tasked with proposing a numerically sound algorithm for evaluating f(x) as it approaches 0.

My initial thought would be to take the taylor series of both the sin function and the denominator, this gives me

$1 + x - \frac{x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120}}{x + x^2 + \frac{x^3}{2}}$

However, this doesn't really seem more, "numerically sound".

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try rewriting the fraction as $\frac{\sin x}{x} e^{-x}$ first.

Comment: What would that accomplish?  I would still just have additions and subtractions of Taylor series expansions, which aren't as precise as multiplication and division are they?  I could be wrong here, just my initial thought from your comment.

Comment: The factor $\sin(x)/x$ has a very simple Taylor series, and so does the factor $e^{-x}$.  Write down a few terms of each, then multiply them.

Comment: Right, but doing so still leaves me with

1 + x - $((x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6})* (\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}-\frac{x^6}{5040}))$

This doesn't simplify the algorithm, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use what you already did and perform the long division. This would lead to $$f(x) = 1 + x - \frac{\sin(x)} {x\,e^{x}}=2 x-\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Using more terms for numerator would lead to $$f(x)=2 x-\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^4}{30}-\frac{x^5}{90}+O\left(x^6\right)$$

To avoid the long division, as suggested by  Antonio Vargas, the simplest is effectively to write $$f(x)=1+x-  \frac{\sin(x)} {x}e^{-x}=1+x-\Big(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}-\frac{x^6}{5040}+O\left(x^8\right)\Big)\times$$ $$\Big(1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{x^6}{720}+O\left
   (x^7\right)\Big)$$ and multiply.

For illustration purposes, I generated a table (values of $x$ and $f(x)$ computed and approximated) (Fortran code using double precision). You could notice that some chaos appears with $f(x)$ for $x \lt 10^{-10}$ and that the results are definitely wrong when $x$ approaches $10^{-20}$ which is the order of magnitude of machine accuracy.

```
1.00D-01        1.9666989048D-01        1.9666988889D-01
1.00D-02        1.9966666999D-02        1.9966666999D-02
1.00D-03        1.9996666667D-03        1.9996666667D-03
1.00D-04        1.9999666667D-04        1.9999666667D-04
1.00D-05        1.9999966667D-05        1.9999966667D-05
1.00D-06        1.9999996667D-06        1.9999996667D-06
1.00D-07        1.9999999667D-07        1.9999999667D-07
1.00D-08        1.9999999967D-08        1.9999999967D-08
1.00D-09        1.9999999997D-09        1.9999999997D-09
1.00D-10        2.0000000001D-10        2.0000000000D-10
1.00D-11        2.0000000029D-11        2.0000000000D-11
1.00D-12        1.9999999920D-12        2.0000000000D-12
1.00D-13        1.9999995583D-13        2.0000000000D-13
1.00D-14        2.0000006425D-14        2.0000000000D-14
1.00D-15        1.9999735375D-15        2.0000000000D-15
1.00D-16        1.9998109071D-16        2.0000000000D-16
1.00D-17        2.0003530082D-17        2.0000000000D-17
1.00D-18        1.8973538018D-18        2.0000000000D-18
1.00D-19        2.1684043450D-19        2.0000000000D-19
1.00D-20        0.0000000000D+00        2.0000000000D-20
1.00D-21        0.0000000000D+00        2.0000000000D-21
1.00D-22        0.0000000000D+00        2.0000000000D-22
1.00D-23        0.0000000000D+00        2.0000000000D-23
1.00D-24        0.0000000000D+00        2.0000000000D-24
1.00D-25        0.0000000000D+00        2.0000000000D-25
```

Comment: What does this give me as my final algorithm?  I just take the product of those two taylor series results as you have shown and multiply them together?  How is that more Sound?? It seems a lot more complicated

Comment: The problem is that, close to $x=0$, $\frac{\sin(x)} {x\,e^{x}}=1-x+\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$ so $f(x)\approx \frac{x^2}{3}$ which is very close to $0$ when $|x| \lt \sqrt{3\epsilon}$,  $\epsilon$ being machine accuracy